Change Default Checked Icon of PrimeNG Checkbox via Global Styles
I am updating Angular from version 15 to 17. Therefore I also need to update primeNG.
I am having trouble to change the default checked icon of the checkbox.
Changing the Icon either per icon template or per the new property checkboxIcon is not an option for me, as I would need to change my html templates everywhere I use <p-checkbox> - does not seem elegant to me.
Before, I could change the icon in one global css file via the content property and the pseudo selector ::before. Something like
.p-checkbox-box.p-highlight .p-checkbox-icon::before {
  content: '\e90b';
  font-family: 'primeicons' !important;
  font-size: 18px;
}

So I would like to change the icon this way.
Find a minimal Angular/PrimeNG Setup here.

You can use the below CSS
Added white color to icon for good contrast ratio
global-styles.scss
.p-checkbox-box.p-highlight .p-element.p-icon-wrapper::before {
  content: '\e90b';
  font-family: 'primeicons' !important;
  font-size: 18px;
  color: white;
}

.p-checkbox-box.p-highlight .p-element.p-icon-wrapper svg {
  display: none;
}

Stackblitz Demo
If you want to put in component.ts you need to use ::ng-deep
::ng-deep .p-checkbox-box.p-highlight .p-element.p-icon-wrapper::before {
  content: '\e90b';
  font-family: 'primeicons' !important;
  font-size: 18px;
  color: white;
}

::ng-deep .p-checkbox-box.p-highlight .p-element.p-icon-wrapper svg {
  display: none;
}


Great! Thanks a lot for your help. Do you know though why it is not working, when put into the components style file, even !important does not help?!

how would you apply font-weight to make the icon very bold?

@neukoellnjenny updated my answe we can use ng deep, could you try font weight

I tried font-weight with both pseudo selector :and pseudo element ::, did not work tho

@neukoellnjenny am not sure if it can be done since it's an icon

it can be done, saw it with my own eyes :) it worked with angular 15, something like this
    font-weight: 900;
    text-shadow: 1px 0 0 var(--colorE);
    font-size: 24px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    flex-flow: row wrap;
}```
